# Loss does not reduce when fine-tuning inception v3 for im2txt

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a problem with fine-tuning a pre-trained Inception v3 model for [im2txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/im2txt). For some reason, initial-training did not reduce loss much, and fine-tuning Inception v3 did not reduce any loss for my training data. I am trying to find out why, and any insights would be helpful.

im2txt is a model that takes input of image and prints out a list of captions as outputs. Originally, im2txt prints out a caption as a *coherent sentence*, describing the image. To suit my project, I changed the code and labels in training data so it prints out a *list of words* related to the image.

For example, my image would look like this. Notice that there are a lot of objects in the image than an average Imagenet image:

[image: lady shopping clothes]

My label captions look like this:

```
 female lady woman clothes shop customer
```

I have in total 400,000 images and corresponding label captions. I trained for initial training for 130,000 steps, and fine tune for 170,000 steps. There are in total 750 words in vocabulary. The loss curve for initial-training + fine-tuning (starts at step 130,000) is below:
[image]

Precision and Recall are about 0.35~40.

The configuration file for training is below:

```
# Copyright 2016 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# ==============================================================================

"""Image-to-text model and training configurations."""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function


class ModelConfig(object):
  """Wrapper class for model hyperparameters."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Sets the default model hyperparameters."""
    # File pattern of sharded TFRecord file containing SequenceExample protos.
    # Must be provided in training and evaluation modes.
    self.input_file_pattern = None

    # Image format ("jpeg" or "png").
    self.image_format = "jpeg"

    # Approximate number of values per input shard. Used to ensure sufficient
    # mixing between shards in training.
    self.values_per_input_shard = 2300
    # Minimum number of shards to keep in the input queue.
    self.input_queue_capacity_factor = 2
    # Number of threads for prefetching SequenceExample protos.
    self.num_input_reader_threads = 1

    # Name of the SequenceExample context feature containing image data.
    self.image_feature_name = "image/data"
    # Name of the SequenceExample feature list containing integer captions.
    self.caption_feature_name = "image/caption_ids"

    # Number of unique words in the vocab (plus 1, for <UNK>).
    # The default value is larger than the expected actual vocab size to allow
    # for differences between tokenizer versions used in preprocessing. There is
    # no harm in using a value greater than the actual vocab size, but using a
    # value less than the actual vocab size will result in an error.
    self.vocab_size = 750

    # Number of threads for image preprocessing. Should be a multiple of 2.
    self.num_preprocess_threads = 4

    # Batch size.
    self.batch_size = 32

    # File containing an Inception v3 checkpoint to initialize the variables
    # of the Inception model. Must be provided when starting training for the
    # first time.
    self.inception_checkpoint_file = None

    # Dimensions of Inception v3 input images.
    self.image_height = 299
    self.image_width = 299

    # Scale used to initialize model variables.
    self.initializer_scale = 0.08

    # LSTM input and output dimensionality, respectively.
    self.embedding_size = 512
    self.num_lstm_units = 512

    # If < 1.0, the dropout keep probability applied to LSTM variables.
    self.lstm_dropout_keep_prob = 0.7


class TrainingConfig(object):
  """Wrapper class for training hyperparameters."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Sets the default training hyperparameters."""
    # Number of examples per epoch of training data.
    self.num_examples_per_epoch = 100000

    # Optimizer for training the model.
    self.optimizer = "SGD"

    # Learning rate for the initial phase of training.
    self.initial_learning_rate = 2.0
    self.learning_rate_decay_factor = 0.5
    self.num_epochs_per_decay = 1.0

    # Learning rate when fine tuning the Inception v3 parameters.
    self.train_inception_learning_rate = 0.005

    # If not None, clip gradients to this value.
    self.clip_gradients = 5.0

    # How many model checkpoints to keep.
    self.max_checkpoints_to_keep = 5
```

Any advice, insights or observations would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that the im2txt is very powerful in the sense that it makes readable sentences. In the sentences one word is related to the adjacent words, that is why it works. In your case, you are changing the model to produce a set of labels which order is not relevant. Actually, in the im2txt model the words "female", "woman" and "lady" are basically the same concept and im2txt can create sentences swiping this words. For example, in the im2txt: "the lady is wearing a nice pink skirt" is the same as "the skirt of the woman is pink", or should be very similar. In your case, if you don't provide some rules to the order of the words it is going to confuse a lot your model and might not learn.

If you want to get a list of labels from an image you should use only an inception model with a multilabel classification (changing the softmax layer by a sigmoid layer and using sigmoid cross entropy as loss function).

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I understand the disadvantages with using im2txt for this problem. I have tried using google inception with sigmoid cross entropy before as my first choice. For some reason, in my case, the inception model basically "cheats" if there are too many  output labels (750 words). It will either gives True for the same set of labels or False for all of them. Is it the same in your case?

Comment: I am using it with hundred of labels without any issues. I am using this `tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(multi_class_labels=labels, logits=logits)` It has to be the logits layer, not the softmax layer of inception. And labels must have 1 for labels and 0 for non-labels.

Comment: Excuse me, but do you happend to have working open source code? I would be very grateful.

Comment: No for this, sorry. But I can spot issues in your code if you show it

Comment: This is my code in Keras. But it uses categorical cross entropy: https://pastebin.com/UVnEKzyk

My colleague did as you said based on the following article: https://medium.com/towards-data-science/multi-label-image-classification-with-inception-net-cbb2ee538e30. He found the same problem. The code he used was here: https://github.com/BartyzalRadek/Multi-label-Inception-net

Comment: `categorica_crossentropy` seems to be only for single-label classification. I am not sure which one is the correct one, I would try with `binary_crossentropy`. Also 300 examples seems like too few examples for this type of problem (although you start with a checkpoint, so it might help a lot). When I load a model from a checkpoint like this I usually reset the last layer, but I have no idea how to do it in keras.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you mind having a look at the code my colleague used?

Comment: I read that post some time ago. It seems ok. It might be something related with the dataset. Try also with a decreasing learning rate. You can use this model https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_v4.py you only have to take the logits from the end points and apply the function I put before. That is what I do basically.

Comment: I forgot. `sigmoid_cross_entropy` applies inside a sigmoid and the cross entropy, if you want to get predictions you must use a sigmoid function with the logits, but don't use that function before `sigmoid_cross_entropy`. I mean, for training use `sigmoid_cross_entropy`, for prediction apply a sigmoid function to the logits. `sigmoid_cross_entropy` applies some math tricks to avoid problems when training (nan values in the loss).